# How to populate a page with data from mysqli associative array

Tags: php, mysql

So say I have an associative array from the query:

```
$product_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db->query("SELECT * FROM business   INNER JOIN  products  USING (v_id) WHERE products.v_id = '$v_id'"));
```

With values:

```
array(4) { 
    ["v_id"]=> string(2) "13" 
    ["p_name"]=> string(6) "Cersei" 
    ["p_photo"]=> string(19) "/images/jkjbskh.jpg" 
    ["p_type"]=> string(7) "Fashion" 
}
```

Suppose there are like, 5 rows, How would one populate an html list such that all the rows are captured

Comment: Run a prepared statement instead of injecting variables directly in the querystring. Then fetch and bind the result. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: you mean, you want to put that into an HTML formatted table, is that what your question is about? Edit: that's what this is to me; see the duplicate for this.

Comment: Let me see if the manual will sort me out